# Problem in giving the initial parameters to depmixS4 package in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

I have initial parameters for HMM model and I want to use depmixS4 package in R on these. 
The parameters are in the form

```
intial_prob_matrix=matrix(c(0.07614213, 0.45177665, 0.47208122), nrow=1, 
ncol=3, byrow = TRUE) 

transition_matrix=matrix(c(0.46666667,0.46666667,0.06666667, 
                     0.06741573,0.5617978,0.37078652, 
                     0.02173913,0.3478261,0.63043478), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, 
byrow = TRUE) 

meanval_matrix=matrix(c(545.1737,545.1737,803.5235, 
                        565.7763,673.8019,797.5283, 
                        733.9332,1006.3571,1383.5395), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, 
byrow = TRUE) 

sigmaval_matrix=matrix(c(82.19592,13.64243,57.07868, 
                         65.32724,13.38910,81.66209, 
                         97.62573,71.09579,115.55612), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, 
byrow = TRUE) 

coeffval_matrix=matrix(c(0.1295604,0.6464059,0.2240336, 
                         0.2091671,0.5267220,0.2641110, 
                         0.3430697,0.3350215,0.3219088), nrow = 3, ncol = 
3, byrow = TRUE) 

emission_matrix=list(meanval_matrix,sigmaval_matrix,coeffval_matrix)
```

powerdf is a column from my dataset Data which look like something = 19.0, 18.0, 
24.0...............it has some 30 thousand rows

I tried  using the code below and got an error

```
powerdf <- data.frame(power=Data$power) 
mod= depmix( response = power~1, data = powerdf, nstates=3, 
                               instart=intial_prob_matrix, 
    trstart=transition_matrix, respstart=emission_matrix)
```

Error in makeResponseModels(response = response, data = data, nstates = 
nstates,  :  'respstart' has incorrect length, it should be 6

I cannot change my emission matrix, it would always be list of matrix (mean 
, sigma and weighted coefficient mixture which represent Gaussian mixture component)

I thought to change the response but I am unable to figure out the right 
response

Can someone guide me how can I solve this problem, by giving the 
parameters defined above?

Thanks & Regards

Niharika Singhal

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, a bit late with this answer

In your response model, you specify that a single variable (power) is modeled with an intercept only model. As no family is specified, this defaults to a linear Gaussian model, with only an intercept. Such a model has two parameters (an intercept, which is the mean of the distribution, and a standard deviation of the distribution). In a 3-state HMM, there are three of such response models, so the total number of parameters is 6. If you run

```
mod= depmix( response = power~1, data = powerdf, nstates=3, 
                           instart=intial_prob_matrix, 
trstart=transition_matrix)
getpars(mod)
```

You will see all the parameters in the model, with the last 6 being for the responses.

I con't understand why the meanval_matrix, sigmaval_matrix, and coeffval_matrix all are 3 by 3 matrices, but you would want to pick three means and three standard deviations from these as initial values for respstart, I guess.